# BASH: Double quotes around part of array output?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I've spent way to long trying to figure this out, so I hope someone can shed some light on this.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME="`hostname`"
JSONFILE="${HOSTNAME}.json"

#####################
#     FUNCTIONS     #
#####################
function getfilesystems() {
  count=0;
  FILESYSTEMS=()
  SAVEIFS=$IFS
  IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
  for fs in `df -P | awk 'NR!=1'`; do
    FILESYSTEMS+=("fs$count=${fs}")
    (( count++ ))
  done
  echo "${FILESYSTEMS[@]}"
  IFS=$SAVEIFS
}

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

jo -p serverdata="$(jo hostname=${HOSTNAME} reportdata="$(date)" storage="$(jo -p "$(getfilesystems)")")"

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

I'm trying to focus on this part `FILESYSTEMS+=("fs$count=${fs}")`

Right now, the output is this:

```
'fs0=/dev/mapper/vg_rpidalappnfs-LogVol00                                           10190136      5486908      4178940      57% /' 'fs1=tmpfs                                                                           1962684            4      1962680       1% /dev/shm' 'fs2=/dev/sda1                                                                        194241       104145        79856      57% /boot'
```

It's almost what I want.  What I need is this (see the quotes difference?):

```
fs0="/dev/mapper/vg_rpidalappnfs-LogVol00                                           10190136      5486908      4178940      57% /" fs1="tmpfs                                                                           1962684            4      1962680       1% /dev/shm" fs2="/dev/sda1                                                                        194241       104145        79856      57% /boot"
```

I've literally been trying to get this to work for about an hour and I just can't seem to get past this one part.

The help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you want *any* quotes in the output; don't confuse syntactic quotes with literal quotes. You also don't really need an array in `getfilesystems` if all you are going to do is output the entire contents at the end; you can just write each filesystem out as you discover it.

Comment: Bash already sets the shell variable `HOSTNAME` for you, by the way.

Comment: You can probably define the function simply as `getfilesystems () { df -P | awk 'NR != 1 {print "fs"(NR-2)"="$0;}'; }`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - learned something new today; did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the doublequote by a backslash:

```
FILESYSTEMS+=("fs$count=\"${fs}")
```

But I fear you won't need the doublequotes in the output in the end, but I'm not familiar with `jo`.

Comment: Already tried this before posting the questions; it did not work as expected.

Comment: I take that back, I think this technically does what I need, but I think the `jo` application is messing up my output and causing it to add escapes in the shell, so I might have looked at this the wrong way when I first tried this before the question.